# Doctrine inheritance, base class and two subtypes

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine

I need to handle 3 entities which cover the same table 'users':

- `User`: covers the users class and is involved in some authentication/validation services.
- `Driver`: extends a `User` and it's related to some other tables. Also involved in different services.
- `Passenger`: extends a `User` and it's related to another tables. Also involved in different services.

All records on `users` table are Users. Those records with `is_driver=0` are passengers and those with `is_driver=1` are drivers.

I know I can do a mapped super class for the users table and the discriminator would be is_driver. So Passenger entity and Driver entity would extend this. The problem I see is that I can't create an User entity that extend this mapped super class because it has no discriminator, any record is a User.

There is an existing database and I'm migrating the project, there is a column `is_driver` which differentiates if a user is a driver or a passenger (tiny int 0 or 1). Now I'd like to have 3 entities.

- `User`: generic (any row)
- `Driver`: those rows with is_driver=1
- `Passenger`: those rows with is_driver=0

Ideally all would be attached in the ORM in some way to the `users` table, and driver and passenger need also to be associated to different entities separately.

Comment: I can't follow your question. Is this `is_driver` column an existing database column you need to migrate into your application? If yes what is the discriminator value for a `User`? `null`? Or why don't you use a `type` discriminator with possible values i.e. `user|driver|passenger`?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it as well as I'd like. Please, check edits.

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is using inheritance for Driver & Passenger, but User is just an Entity that happens to map to the same table. They can all have a shared interface, to make it clear in code, that when you expect a `UserInterface` (not from security, but your own) it can be a User, Driver or Passenger. This might lead to inconsistent data though and might not work at all. If no other application is writing to the db you could also split up the table: e.g. have a user table with an associated (driver/passenger)table that contains the user_id and is_driver columns.

Comment: Have you considered thinking about it in a different way? Just have a User-class that maps to the database and whenever you want to know if they are Driver/Passenger or neither you call `isDriver()` and `isPassenger()` on the User? So basically have Driver and Passenger not be separate classes at all. Depending on your existing code that might mean updating a lot of code, though.

Comment: It could, but a Driver is related to a Car, a Passenger is related to a Company, etc... they indeed are different and I'd like to map them separately with these relations onto the ORM